# can't see mesh in camera view

Tags: rendering, camera, scale

First I have a huge scene [image]

Then I addea a camera and I chose that given view and pressed clt+Alt+numpad 0
then it shows like this[image]

I tried increasing decreasing focal length,size of camera,shift+f to move my camera but nothing worked anyone got a idea??please share if you know,, your answer is highly apprecited

Answer (score 8):

The Problem is that the camera is too far away for the default camera to see.

To fix this, change the clipping under the camera settings to something higher until you can see the object you are looking for. Depending on how far away the object is, you might have to set it quite high.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just press the home button when you are in the camera view. No need to adjust clipping. At least that's how I solved it for myself after several unsuccessful searches.